Problems with remote environment
I'm developing a web platform in Next, my database in Supabase and I uploaded it to Vercel. I did some basic server actions for CRUD, when I tested in the local environment they all worked perfectly, however when I tested in the remote Vercel environment, the read, update and delete work normally, but the insert in the database does not, it kind of holds it back the insertion, after I navigate through the page it does it.
I tried some debug recommendations but couldn't find the source of the problem.
